# Multiple radio button selection without the loading

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, drupal-webform

I have gota a form with 2 questions, each with a radio buttons. When I click on a radio buttons either of the questions, I want the event #edit-next to fire, which will make effect on the drupal form

at the moment when i click on 1 questions radio button the event fires but i want 2 radio buttons 1 from each question for the the event to fire

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.form-radio').click(function() { $('#edit-next').click(); });
});
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

this is the form below

http://goo.gl/bUqvZ

as you can see when you click on one question the whole page loads what i want is when u click on both question then the whole page loads or even better if i could somehow put jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same class name for all radio button ,and i hope left hand side question set and right hand side question set are in diff form.

```
     $('.form-radio').click(function(){
        if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked &&   document.getElementById('radio2').checked){
            $('#button3').click();
      }
  });
```

It should work

Comment: hi i tried using the code on this page but its not seem to work i put the code in jqueri.js i m trying to get it on this page http://goo.gl/XRHzQ